# Why is port 20 still blocked when I have added it to Accept in iptables

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, ubuntu-9.10, ftp

I am trying to open the FTP Ports on my server. I have vsftpd installed on the server already. However I am unable to reach the server on ports 20 and 21

Somehow it is allowing me to access port 21 at the moment.

I am running Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic) I also ran: modprobe ip_conntrack modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp

The following is the iptables -L on my server

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             poseidon.valltek.com tcp dpts:ftp-data:ftp

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  poseidon.valltek.com  anywhere            tcp dpts:ftp-data:ftp
```

I have been using www.ping.eu/port-chk/ to check the port. Just incase it was an issue with my local machine.

Thanks.

Comment: Your police for all the chains is ACCEPT, and you do not appear to have any DENY rules.  This means you are not blocking anything, and everything should be getting through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You may want to add `ip_nat_ftp` to your list aswell as making sure everything is being loaded with using the command `lsmod`**

Is that a home server, from some internet provider ? if so you may be having a common issue where usually internet providers block ports from 1 to 1024 from their residential users so they dont create home servers (this approch is used in several countries afaik).

If that is not the case, make sure you have set ip_forward aswell.

```
sudo echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_foward
```

**Firewall (iptables)**

```
# Allow FTP connections @ port 21
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --sport 21 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow Active FTP Connections
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 20 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 20 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 

# Allow Passive FTP Connections
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024:  -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024:  -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

You said `Somehow it is allowing me to access port 21 at the moment.`, can you download or upload anything ? if so then it how it should be see bellow:

**Active FTP**

In active mode FTP the client connects from a random unprivileged port (N > 1023) to the FTP server's command port, port 21. Then, the client starts listening to port N+1 and sends the FTP command PORT N+1 to the FTP server. The server will then connect back to the client's specified data port from its local data port, which is port 20.

From the server-side firewall's standpoint, to support active mode FTP the following communication channels need to be opened:

```
* FTP server's port 21 from anywhere (Client initiates connection)
* FTP server's port 21 to ports > 1023 (Server responds to client's control port)
* FTP server's port 20 to ports > 1023 (Server initiates data connection to client's data port)
* FTP server's port 20 from ports > 1023 (Client sends ACKs to server's data port)
```

**Passive FTP**

In order to resolve the issue of the server initiating the connection to the client a different method for FTP connections was developed. This was known as passive mode, or PASV, after the command used by the client to tell the server it is in passive mode.

In passive mode FTP the client initiates both connections to the server, solving the problem of firewalls filtering the incoming data port connection to the client from the server. When opening an FTP connection, the client opens two random unprivileged ports locally (N > 1023 and N+1). The first port contacts the server on port 21, but instead of then issuing a PORT command and allowing the server to connect back to its data port, the client will issue the PASV command. The result of this is that the server then opens a random unprivileged port (P > 1023) and sends the PORT P command back to the client. The client then initiates the connection from port N+1 to port P on the server to transfer data.

From the server-side firewall's standpoint, to support passive mode FTP the following communication channels need to be opened:

```
* FTP server's port 21 from anywhere (Client initiates connection)
* FTP server's port 21 to ports > 1023 (Server responds to client's control port)
* FTP server's ports > 1023 from anywhere (Client initiates data connection to random port specified by server)
* FTP server's ports > 1023 to remote ports > 1023 (Server sends ACKs (and data) to client's data port)
```